# Select all payments by zip code

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a query that will show total payments by zip code. Here is what my database looks like.  Think I have to join the tables but not sure.  Thanks for helping

```
PERMITS-table
permitID
zipCode

PAYMENTS-table
permitID
payment
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT permits.permitID, permits.zipCode, payments.payment, payments.permitID 
FROM permits INNER JOIN Payments ON payments.permitID = permits.permitID 
GROUP BY zip
```

Comment: select permits.permitID, permits.zipCode, payments.payment, payments.permitID
from permits
inner join Payments
on payments.permitID = permits.permitID
group by zip

Comment: Read up on [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @Mr.Blue I've added it for you already, but next time please just edit the question and add the query in there. Code can't be formatted nicely in the comments, and comments are meant to be non-permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT permits.zipCode, SUM(payments.payment) 
FROM   permits 
       JOIN payments 
         ON permits.permitID = payments.permitID
GROUP  BY permits.zipCode
```

Comment: Nothing offensive, the answer first was wrong, and only then, I kept my answer. But later, the answer was corrected!!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a sum of the payments.

```
select
    p.Zipcode
   ,pay.sum(payments)
from permits p
   join payments pay 
       on p.permitID = pay.PermitID
group by p.zipcode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT permits.zipCode,SUM( payments.payment)
FROM permits 
INNER JOIN Payments 
  ON payments.permitID = permits.permitID 
GROUP BY permits.zipCode
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the folllowing query.
No need to group, as grouping does exactly what it sounds like.
You wish to join two table based on a key and then filter the results based on a condition you set.

```
SELECT
  paym.*
FROM 
  PAYMENTS-table paym
INNER JOIN
  PERMITS-table perm ON paym.permitID = perm.permitId
WHERE
  perm.zipCode = 'A1234'
```

You should also keep in mind that there are quite a few JOIN types, this diagram sums it up pretty nicely:

[image]